# TypeScript compile crashes VS2012 with Web Essentials 1.8

Tags: typescript, web-essentials

I just updated to Web Essentials 1.8 and now whenever I build/compile any TypeScript file it crashes VS2012.  Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still crashes but found a temporary fix (See my Q&A post): http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6/view/Discussions/0?showDiscussionForm=True

Comment: I posted a bug to Mads about this a couple of days ago, and he sent me a patched version which fixed the problem. I had assumed this had been rolled into the release version by now. My workaround was the same as yours.

Answer (score 2):

Get the latest nightly build that has a fix for this: http://madskristensen.net/custom/webessentials2012.vsix?1.8.9.1